# Customise calendar for both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, xcode8

I need a calendar for my application where I can pick a single date and show unavailable & available dates in the calendar for the event. I'm building android app in Java - Android Studio and IOS App in objective C - Xcode. I'm looking for an existing built in library for this purpose. If it is available for both Android and IOS that will be great. If not, i need a best suggestion to achieve this !!

I have seen few reference links like below:

(Android) https://github.com/square/android-times-square

(IOS) https://github.com/guicocoa/calendar

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

For ios you can use : https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

This is fully customizable iOS calendar library, compatible with Objective-C and Swift

Comment: Hi Jagdeep ! Thanks for your help. This is working for me. I have to show few dates as selected dates and few dates as available dates in FSCalendar?

Also any similar library available for android ?

Comment: you can show selected date as this : self.calendar.select(date). And for android you can check for : https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: Thanks Jagdeep. I will look into this and let you know !!

Comment: Hi Jagdeep, I tried it: [self.Calendar selectDate:date]; It's not working. I also enabled multiple selection in the calendar.

Comment: What issue you are facing, when you trying to select date as this.

Comment: Hi Jagdeep, I need to show few dates to be selected. To show them they are available dates. Working on the same in the Android Calendar as well.

Comment: [self.Calendar selectDate:date]; this is correct way to select date. If this is not working then check you code carefully, may be you are doing wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Jagdeep ! I will look into this and let you know.

Comment: i used this library too.

Answer (score 2):

The best Pod for iOS is this: https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar

But it's only for iOS.

Comment: Hi oskarko ! Thanks for your help. This is available in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

i have used this in mine live projects it works great.

https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar

or you can also use some reference from  here
https://cocoapods.org/?q=calenda

best references are from here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=calendar

Comment: CVCalendar is in swift !?